# Standard blue white buttons for iPhone

Tags: iphone

The default rounded rect button for the iPhone does not look as good as a lot of common apps that have the blue background, white background, red background, thicker borders, etc.  Is there documentation on what size for the radius of the rounded rect, or which images to use, where to get the images, etc?  Thanks.

Comment: "blue background, white background, red background, thicker borders" What on earth are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Apple the size of a button should be 44 x 44 so that the user can easily use the buttons with a finger tap.

EDIT : Additionally go through the iOS Human Interface Guidelines document linked below (specifically the Rounded Rectangle Button part)

http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html